# How to setup a CompareValidator based on based on a different web control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, comparevalidator

```
<asp: CompareValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" 
      ControlToValidate="TextBox13" 
      ValidationExpression="RadioButtonList5.Text == 'No'">
    Please Answer Question
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`
```

I would like to setup a `CompareValidator` for a text box, based upon the response from a `RadioButton`.

I have a web page where the user is supposed to answer several questions. If the user answers no to question 5 (`RadioButtonList5` Yes/No) then in question 6 they are supposed to enter a date.

I know the `ValidationExpression` is incorrect. I just need help figuring out how to set it up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since user input determines if the compare validator is enabled or not, then you need to use JavaScript/jQuery code, like this:

```
// This will enable the validator
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator5"), true);

// This will disable the validator
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator5"), false);
```

So you will need to run the above code in a change handler for the radio button list, like this:

```
$("#<%=RadioButtonList5.ClientID%> input").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Yes") {
        // Enable or disable compare validator
    }
    if($(this).val() == "No") {
        // Enable or disable compare validator
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the Help. Quick question, so I'm going to need the original CompareValidator plus the validatorEnable(true/false) plus the Jquery. correct? Do I have to wrap the ValidatorEnable and Jquery in a script tag?

Comment: Yes, the `ValidatorEnable` is a JavaScript method so that and any jQuery code you write will need to be inside of a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Soul - glad this helped you. Feel free to up-vote my answer when you can. :-)

Comment: Nice! will do for sure, thnks again!